# Strange error from CBuilder at compile time using dynamic_cast for similar types

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Using C++ Builder 5.0

```
template <class HYPERSPACE>
inline
bool IsAtLeastHYPERSPACE(hyperspace_t **_)

     { return (dynamic_cast<HYPERSPACE **>(_) != 0); }
```

that produces a compile error E2031 : cannot cast from 'hyperspace_t **' to 'hyperspace_t **'...

So should I assume that C++ cannot cast from a class to the SAME class pointer ?
Then, how to check if the class of an object's pointer is an overloaded class ?

Really blocked by that strange error....

Help appreciated... So I could at least compile...

Comment: casting double pointer is a code smell for me. Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Oups... I found my mistake :

As the parameter is an array of pointers of a parent class, I cannot cast it to an array of pointers to a derived class, but only cast to a derived class, a specific element of that source array...

So the code became...

```
template <class HYPERSPACE>
inline
bool IsAtLeastHYPERSPACE(hyperspace_t **_)

     { return (dynamic_cast<HYPERSPACE *>(_[0]) != 0); }
```

Notice `_[0]` instead of `_` and `HYPERSPACE *` instead of `HYPERSPACE **`

That's all folks...

Comment: you are doing something very strange. I'm pretty sure there is better way to do it besides use of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Well...for the moment that works fine according to my gal that is to maintain an array of virtual classes... and check that an element belongs at least to a given class... The real use is a class acting like a TDataSet over a template <T> MyList : TList... So I can easily fetch a TMathematicalOperator to another within  a TList of TOperator....